# What does a lazy val do?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I noticed that Scala provide `lazy vals`. But I don't get what they do.

```
scala> val x = 15
x: Int = 15

scala> lazy val y = 13
y: Int = <lazy>

scala> x
res0: Int = 15

scala> y
res1: Int = 13
```

The [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) shows that `y` is a `lazy val`, but how is it different from a normal `val`?

Answer (score 363, accepted):

The difference between them is, that a `val` is executed when it is defined whereas a `lazy val` is executed when it is accessed the first time.

```
scala> val x = { println("x"); 15 }
x
x: Int = 15

scala> lazy val y = { println("y"); 13 }
y: Int = <lazy>

scala> x
res2: Int = 15

scala> y
y
res3: Int = 13

scala> y
res4: Int = 13
```

In contrast to a method (defined with `def`) a `lazy val` is executed once and then never again. This can be useful when an operation takes long time to complete and when it is not sure if it is later used.

```
scala> class X { val x = { Thread.sleep(2000); 15 } }
defined class X

scala> class Y { lazy val y = { Thread.sleep(2000); 13 } }
defined class Y

scala> new X
res5: X = X@262505b7 // we have to wait two seconds to the result

scala> new Y
res6: Y = Y@1555bd22 // this appears immediately
```

Here, when the values `x` and `y` are never used, only `x` unnecessarily wasting resources. If we suppose that `y` has no side effects and that we do not know how often it is accessed (never, once, thousands of times) it is useless to declare it as `def` since we don't want to execute it several times.

If you want to know how `lazy vals` are implemented, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041253/whats-the-hidden-cost-of-lazy-val-scala).

Comment: As a supplemental: @ViktorKlang posted on Twitter: ["Little known Scala fact: if the initialization of a lazy val throws 
an exception, it will attempt to reinitialize the val at next access."](https://twitter.com/#!/viktorklang/status/104483846002704384)

Comment: @PeterSchmitz And I find this terrible. Compare with [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization#exceptions-in-lazy-objects) in .NET

Answer (score 65):

This feature helps not only delaying expensive calculations, but is also useful to construct mutual dependent or cyclic structures. E.g. this leads to an stack overflow:

```
trait Foo { val foo: Foo }
case class Fee extends Foo { val foo = Faa() }
case class Faa extends Foo { val foo = Fee() }

println(Fee().foo)
//StackOverflowException
```

But with lazy vals it works fine

```
trait Foo { val foo: Foo }
case class Fee extends Foo { lazy val foo = Faa() }
case class Faa extends Foo { lazy val foo = Fee() }

println(Fee().foo)
//Faa()
```

Comment: But it will lead to the same StackOverflowException if your toString method outputs "foo" attribute. Nice example of "lazy" anyway!!!

Answer (score 46):

I understand that the answer is given but I wrote a simple example to make it easy to understand for beginners like me:

```
var x = { println("x"); 15 }
lazy val y = { println("y"); x + 1 }
println("-----")
x = 17
println("y is: " + y)
```

Output of above code is:

```
x
-----
y
y is: 18
```

As it can be seen, x is printed when it's initialized, but y is not printed when it's initialized in same way (I have taken x as var intentionally here - to explain when y gets initialized). Next when y is called, it's initialized as well as value of last 'x' is taken into consideration but not the old one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 45):

A lazy val is most easily understood as a "[memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (no-arg) def".

Like a def, a lazy val is not evaluated until it is invoked.  But the result is saved so that subsequent invocations return the saved value.  The memoized result takes up space in your data structure, like a val.

As others have mentioned, the use cases for a lazy val are to defer expensive computations until they are needed and store their results, and to solve certain circular dependencies between values.

Lazy vals are in fact implemented more or less as memoized defs.  You can read about the details of their implementation here:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html

Comment: maybe rather as a "memoized def that takes 0 arguments".

Answer (score 19):

Also `lazy` is useful without cyclic dependencies, as in the following code:

```
abstract class X {
  val x: String
  println ("x is "+x.length)
}

object Y extends X { val x = "Hello" }
Y
```

Accessing `Y` will now throw null pointer exception, because `x` is not yet initialized.
The following, however, works fine:

```
abstract class X {
  val x: String
  println ("x is "+x.length)
}

object Y extends X { lazy val x = "Hello" }
Y
```

EDIT: the following will also work:

```
object Y extends { val x = "Hello" } with X
```

This is called an "early initializer". See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712468/in-scala-what-is-an-early-initializer) for more details.

Comment: Can you clarify why the declaration of Y does not immediately initialize the variable "x" in the first example before calling the parent constructor?

Comment: Because superclass constructor is first one that gets implicitly called.

Comment: @Ashoat Please see [this link](https://github.com/scala/scala.github.com/blob/master/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.md) for an explanation of why it is not initialized.

Answer (score 4):

A demonstration of `lazy` - as defined above - execution when defined vs execution when accessed: (using 2.12.7 scala shell)

```
// compiler says this is ok when it is lazy
scala> lazy val t: Int = t 
t: Int = <lazy>
//however when executed, t recursively calls itself, and causes a StackOverflowError
scala> t             
java.lang.StackOverflowError
...

// when the t is initialized to itself un-lazily, the compiler warns you of the recursive call
scala> val t: Int = t
<console>:12: warning: value t does nothing other than call itself recursively
   val t: Int = t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> lazy val lazyEight = {
     |   println("I am lazy !")
     |   8
     | }
lazyEight: Int = <lazy>

scala> lazyEight
I am lazy !
res1: Int = 8
```

- All vals are initialized during object construction
- Use lazy keyword to defer initialization until first usage
- **Attention**: Lazy vals are not final and therefore might show performance drawbacks