# NullPointerException on a listener pattern in scala

Tags: list, class, scala, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to create a listener design Pattern like that:

```
abstract class Listener(g: Engine) {
  g.addListener(this)
}
class Listener1(g: Engine) extends Listener(g)
class Listener2(g: Engine) extends Listener(g)

class Engine {
  val listener1 = new Listener1(this)
  val listener2 = new Listener2(this)  

  var listeners: List[Listener] = Nil
  def addListener(g: Listener) = {
    listeners = g::listeners
  }
}
```

But if fails with a `NullPointerException`, because `listeners` is initially equal to `null` when `listener1` and `listener2` are created.

How do I overcome this problem?

**EDIT:** I tried the following:

```
  def addListener(g: Listener) = {
    if(listeners == null) {
      listeners = List(g)
    } else {
      listeners = g::listeners
    }
  }
```

But the problem is that after the class is initialized, listeners = Nil.
I need a better design pattern to achieve my goal.

**SOLUTION:** Without using lazy val or mutable collections:

```
var listeners: List[Listener] = _
def addListener(g: Listener) = {
  if(listeners == null) 
    listeners = List(g)
  else
    listeners = g::listeners
}
```

Using `_` for initialization instead of 'null' or 'Nil' makes the compiler not to overwrite `listeners` after `listener1` and `listener2` have been created.

Comment: actually initialization with `_` is identical to setting null to listeners

Comment: No, because if you replace _ by null, then listeners will be equal to null at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a help of [lazy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484928/what-does-a-lazy-val-do) and [mutable collection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html):

```
class Engine {
  val listener1 = new Listener1(this)
  val listener2 = new Listener2(this)  

  lazy val listeners = collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Listener]
  def addListener(g: Listener) {
    listeners += g
  }
}
```

If you badly need immutable List somewhere down the road, just turn buffer into it with `.toList` method in the callplace.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But why? If I understand correctly, the lazy val defines a new class where the content is computed after the first call, isn't it ? But in my case, listeners might not even be defined in the method addListener, even if it is lazy.

Comment: unlike plain val, lazy val defers initialization to the moment of first access (and [has quite complicated implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041253/whats-the-hidden-cost-of-scalas-lazy-val)) -- it is defined but just not set yet. Both lazy or not, listeners variable acts like a class field from addListener point of view.

Comment: I accept your solution because I like it, but I also added mine which works without lazy val nor mutable collections.