# When lazy val is initialized?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

When in Scala lazy val initialized? In other words does following code have some benefits from declaring variables as lazy?

```
  lazy val xOption = table.get(x)
  lazy val yOption = table.get(y)
  lazy val xyOption = table.get(x + y)

 (xOption, yOption, xyOption) match { ... }
```

Does `match` operator (method) initialize all three variables?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484928/what-does-a-lazy-val-do

Answer (score 5):

You could remove `match` here:

```
(xOption, yOption, xyOption)
```

This expression creates `Tuple3`. Without syntax sugar:

```
Tuple3.apply(xOption, yOption, xyOption)
```

`apply` method declaration:

```
def apply[T1, T2, T3](_1: T1, _2: T2, _3: T3): (T1, T2, T3)
```

All parameters are `call-by-value`, so parameters values evaluated before `apply` method evaluation.

With `call-by-name` parameters `lazy val` will not be evaluated.

`match` calls `unapply` method, so evaluation depends on `unapply` method implementstion:

```
lazy val a = { println("a"); 1 }
lazy val b = { println("b"); 1 }
lazy val c = { println("c"); 1 }

scala> val s = a #:: b #:: c #:: Stream.empty
a
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s match {
     |   case x #:: _ => x
     | }
b
res0: Int = 1
```

As you can see `c` is not evaluated, `a` is evaluated on `Stream` creation and `b` is evaluated in `#::.unapply` method.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The lazy modiﬁer applies to value deﬁnitions.
>
> A lazy value is initialized the ﬁrst time it is accessed (which might
>   never happen at all). Attempting to access a lazy value during its
>   initialization might lead to looping behavior. If an exception is
>   thrown during initialization, the value is considered uninitialized,
>   and a later access will retry to evaluate its right hand side.

Simply put, it will initialize the first time you use it. In your case the first time `match` expression is called. Though table needs to have `x` by then.

If you see its implementation (as of Scala 2.10, it is changed in the future versions): It uses the famous Double Locking Idiom:
private volatile T result;

```
    public T getValue() {
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = //initialize
                    return result;
                } else {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Lazy vals are initialized on the first access them, it is computed after access and then becomes a simple val, from api point of view ([some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041253/whats-the-hidden-cost-of-scalas-lazy-val) notes about implementation, and [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html) SIP for additional info).

So yes if your patMat construct is the first place where you access to your vals it will make a tuple of three elements with vals value.

And `match` **IS NOT A METHOD** or operator it is a language level construct.