# Scala collection that accepts pass-by-name parameters

Tags: scala, collections, pass-by-name

Does such collection exist?

At the moment the code I have doesn't compile:

```
object pagerank {
    // TODO fixme
    val totalNodes: BigDecimal = 4

    class Node(in: => List[Node], out: => List[Node]) {
        def rank: BigDecimal = {
            in.foldLeft(BigDecimal(0))((sum, node) => sum + node.rank) + (1 / totalNodes / out.size)
        }
    }

    val d: Node = new Node(Nil, List(a, b, c))
    val b: Node = new Node(List(d), List(a, c))
    val c: Node = new Node(List(b, d), List(a))
    val a: Node = new Node(List(b, c, d), Nil)

  b.rank
}
```

Erros are:

- forward reference extends over definition of value d
- forward reference extends over definition of value c
- forward reference extends over definition of value b
- forward reference extends over definition of value a

Comment: Does making a,b,c,d `lazy val`s help?

Comment: Also, read [What does a lazy val do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7484928/205936) and [What's the hidden cost of a lazy val?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3041253/205936)

Comment: Yes, adding "lazy" before a, b, c, d vals helped :)

Comment: Now all I have to do is finish the logic. Right now it's not right.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck and have fun! (Feel free to post the solution yourself and accept it)