# transform anorm (play framework) value before binding

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a case class representing my domain:

```
case class MyModel(rawValue: String, transformedValue: String)
```

rawValue maps to a value in the database and is properly parsed and bound.  What I am trying to do is add `transformedValue` to my model: this value is just some arbitrary transformation that I perform on the rawValue.  It *does not* map to any data in the database / query.

I have a parser (prior to adding `transformedValue`) that looks like this:

```
val parser = {
  get[String]("rawValue") map {
    case rawValue => MyModel(rawValue)
  }
}
```

Since `MyModel` is immutible and I can't insert `transformedValue` into it after its been created, what and where is the best way to do and add this transformation (e.g. adding ad-hoc values to the Model) preferably without using vars?

Coming from Java, I would probably just have added a `getTransformedValue` getter to the domain class that performs this transformation on the rawValue attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `transformedValue` seems to be a derived property, and not something that would be supplied in the constructor, you can define it as an attribute in the body of the function, possibly using the `lazy` qualifier so that it will only be computed on-demand (and just once for instance):

```
case class MyModel(rawValue: String) {
  lazy val transformedValue: String = {
    // Transformation logic, e.g.
    rawValue.toLowerCase()
  }
}
```

`val` is evaluated when defined; `def` is evaluated when called. A `lazy val` is evaluated when it is accessed the first time.

It may be appropriate to use `lazy` in the case of an expensive computation that is rarely needed, or when logic requires it. But for most cases a regular `val` should be used. [Quoting](https://twitter.com/djspiewak/status/302489756552536064):

> lazy val is *not* free (or even cheap). Use it only if you absolutely need laziness for correctness, not for optimization.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like the solution I posted before I saw this. I like the idea of using 'lazy'. Could you comment on the differences by using val instead of def (like I did in my solution)?

Comment: `val` is evaluated when defined; `def` is evaluated when called. A `lazy val` is evaluated when it is accessed the first time. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7484933/376366

Comment: See the updated answer for clarification about when to use lazy val instead of val.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you wouldn't just do the transformation in the parser itself:

```
def transformation(rawValue: String): String = ...

val parser = {
    get[String]("rawValue") map {
        case rawValue => MyModel(rawValue, transformation(rawValue))
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to do it there for some reason, you can use `copy` to create a new copy of `MyModel` with a new value:

```
val model = MyModel("value", ..)

val modelWithTransform = model.copy(transformedValue = transformation(model.rawValue))
```

You could also overload `apply` to automatically apply the transformation within the companion object:

```
case class MyModel(rawValue: String, transformedValue: String)

object MyModel {

    def apply(value: String): MyModel = MyModel(rawValue, transformation(rawValue))

    val parser = {
        get[String]("rawValue") map {
            case rawValue => MyModel(rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

`MyModel` may be immutable, but you can always create another copy of it with some values changed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added my solution right before I saw this and would value your opinion comparing the two..your solution does appear to be a bit more complex

Comment: @oym Not really, just taking advantage of some syntactic sugar. With this method you'll only ever do the computation once, and it'll be available as soon as it's parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was easier than I thought and the solution did look like what I said I would have done in java:

I just add a function to MyModel that does this transformation:

```
case class MyModel(rawValue: String) {
  def transformedValue = {
    // do the transformation here and return it
  }
}
```

Comment: This will compute the transformation each time it is referenced. To do it only once, see my answer.

Comment: Oh I see. you can't add 'lazy' to a def. only to a val.