# How do you comment a line in .sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

This may sound like a stupid question, but I've been searching all over the internet on how to comment a line in an sbt file. Does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`//` creates the comment.
It is rather easy to find.

Edit: An sbt build file uses Scala syntax with some DSL on top of it. As [per documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Basic-Def.html):

> Each Setting is defined with a Scala expression. The expressions in
>   settings are independent of one another, and they are expressions,
>   rather than complete Scala statements.

So if you wonder what for instance `lazy val root` means you should rather search Scala documentation ([or SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484928/what-does-a-lazy-val-do)) for the answer.

On the other hand many "operators" (like +=, :=) are the part of sbt's DSL - they simply methods explained to some degree in the [settings section](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/More-About-Settings.html).

Comment: Your answer was the easiest thing to find.