# How to Initiate as class member in scala?

Tags: scala, mleap

I have a random number class which generate the random number.However i want it to be Initiate as class member so that we do not need to regenerate in every call.Below is the code at present.

```
import ml.combust.mleap.core.Model
import ml.combust.mleap.core.types._

case class RandomNumberModel() extends Model{

  def apply(input: String):  Double  = {
    val rnd = scala.util.Random
    return rnd.nextFloat
  }

  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType("input" -> ScalarType.String).get

  override def outputSchema: StructType = StructType("output" -> ScalarType.Double ).get

}
```

I am new to scala need suggestion What changes i have to do here ?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
case class RandomNumberModel() extends Model {
  private val rnd = scala.util.Random

  def apply(input: String): Double = rnd.nextFloat

  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType("input" -> ScalarType.String).get

  override def outputSchema: StructType = StructType("output" -> ScalarType.Double ).get

}
```

Comment: Note: if a model can ever be used concurrently, consider https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a response to your own answer, but doesn't fit in a comment.

1. Scala has a built-in and thread-safe alternative to what you do with `var _instance` and `def instance`: [`lazy val`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484928/what-does-a-lazy-val-do). Using it we get

   ```
   object RandomNumberModel {
     // private is still visible in the companion class
     private lazy val instance : Random = scala.util.Random
   }

   // in the class:
   val inst = RandomNumberModel.instance
   ```
2. Since you always need to initialize the instance when you use `RandomNumberModel`, you actually don't get any benefit from `lazy` for this case, only some minor overhead. Non-lazy `val`s in the companion object are only initialized when the class is loaded, e.g. when you create the first instance of the class. So just do `private val instance : Random = scala.util.Random`.
3. You don't need to store a reference which always points to the same instance in the class, this just wastes memory. Better use `RandomNumberModel.instance` directly

   ```
   case class RandomNumberModel() extends Model{
       def apply(input: String):  Double  = {
           RandomNumberModel.instance.nextFloat // why not nextDouble?
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
4. You have multiple models using the same `Random`. If your program ever has multiple threads manipulating models, note

   > [Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

   If you use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) it handles the initialization itself:

   ```
   case class RandomNumberModel() extends Model{
       def apply(input: String):  Double  = {
            ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextFloat
       }

       ...
   }

   // object RandomNumberModel is gone
   ```
5. Do you want all `RandomNumberModel`s to be equal? If not, don't make it `case class`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below will this work fine or here i am doing anything wrong:

```
case class RandomNumberModel() extends Model{
    import RandomNumberModel._
    val inst = instance()

    def apply(input: String):  Double  = {
        inst.nextFloat
    }

    override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType("input" -> ScalarType.String).get

    override def outputSchema: StructType = StructType("output" -> ScalarType.Double ).get
}

object RandomNumberModel {
  private var _instance : Random = null
  def instance() = {
    if (_instance == null)
      _instance = scala.util.Random
    _instance
  }
}
```