# scala lazy val: a good way to go easy on the garbage collector?

Tags: scala

I'm wondering if it makes sense to use `lazy val` to prevent unnecessary heap allocations, thereby making the GC's job a little easier. For instance, I am in the habit of writing code like so:

```
lazy val requiredParameterObject = new Foo {
    val a = new ...
    val b = new ...
    // etc
}

for (a <- collection) a.someFunction(requiredParameterObject)
```

The idea here is that by making `requiredParameterObject` lazy, I am saving a heap allocation in the case that `collection` is empty. But I am wondering: do the internal details of `lazy` make this not an effective performance win?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass `lazy val` by name:

```
lazy val requiredParameterObject = new Foo {
    val a = new ...
    val b = new ...
    // etc
}

class C {
    def someFunction(f: => Foo) {
        f  //(1)
    }
}

val collection = List(new C, new C)
for (a <- collection) a.someFunction(requiredParameterObject)
```

In the code above `Foo` is created once when the first item of a collection accesses it in (`1`) - or never if the collection is empty.

You might also get better results if `requiredParameterObject` is an ordinary function, effectively calling `requiredParameterObject` lazily only when it's needed. However it will call it as many times as the the number of elements in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041253/whats-the-hidden-cost-of-lazy-val-scala) was asked here a while back, but somebody points out there that the implementation of `lazy` varies between Scala compiler versions.  Probably the most authoritative answer you'll get to this question is to write a minimal snippet, like:

```scala
def test(pred : Boolean) {
  lazy val v = // ...
  if (pred)
    doSomething(v)
}
```

run it through your version of `scalac` and then peek at the classfile with `scalap` or `javap` to see what you get.