# How are lazy val class variables implemented in Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, variables, lazy-evaluation, scala-2.10

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3043381/1333025) to [What's the (hidden) cost of Scala's lazy val?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3041253/1333025) shows how they were implemented in Scala 2.7. But as the comments say, this must have changed since then, so I'm curious, what's the current (2.10) implementation of class `lazy val` variables?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Compiled this with scala 2.10.2:

```
class Foo {

  lazy val bar = math.pow(5, 3)

}
```

Then decompiled the result with JD-GUI:

```
import scala.math.package.;
import scala.reflect.ScalaSignature;

@ScalaSignature(bytes="\006\001e1A!\001\002\001\013\t\031ai\\8\013\003\r\tq\001P3naRLhh\001\001\024\005\0011\001CA\004\013\033\005A!\"A\005\002\013M\034\027\r\\1\n\005-A!AB!osJ+g\rC\003\016\001\021\005a\"\001\004=S:LGO\020\013\002\037A\021\001\003A\007\002\005!A!\003\001EC\002\023\0051#A\002cCJ,\022\001\006\t\003\017UI!A\006\005\003\r\021{WO\0317f\021!A\002\001#A!B\023!\022\001\0022be\002\002")
public class Foo {

    private double bar;
    private volatile boolean bitmap$0;

    private double bar$lzycompute() {
        synchronized (this) { 
            if (!this.bitmap$0) { 
                this.bar = package..MODULE$.pow(5.0D, 3.0D); 
                this.bitmap$0 = true; 
            } 
            return this.bar; 
        }  
    } 

    public double bar() { 
        return this.bitmap$0 ? this.bar : bar$lzycompute(); 
    }

}
```

**Edit** - Here's what it looks like for three fields:

```
class Foo {

  lazy val a = math.pow(5, 1)
  lazy val b = math.pow(5, 2)
  lazy val c = math.pow(5, 3)

}
```

Decompiled:

```
import scala.math.package.;
import scala.reflect.ScalaSignature;

@ScalaSignature(bytes="\006\001\0052A!\001\002\001\013\t\031ai\\8\013\003\r\tq\001P3naRLhh\001\001\024\005\0011\001CA\004\013\033\005A!\"A\005\002\013M\034\027\r\\1\n\005-A!AB!osJ+g\rC\003\016\001\021\005a\"\001\004=S:LGO\020\013\002\037A\021\001\003A\007\002\005!A!\003\001EC\002\023\0051#A\001b+\005!\002CA\004\026\023\t1\002B\001\004E_V\024G.\032\005\t1\001A\t\021)Q\005)\005\021\021\r\t\005\t5\001A)\031!C\001'\005\t!\r\003\005\035\001!\005\t\025)\003\025\003\t\021\007\005\003\005\037\001!\025\r\021\"\001\024\003\005\031\007\002\003\021\001\021\003\005\013\025\002\013\002\005\r\004\003")
public class Foo {

    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;

    private volatile byte bitmap$0;

    private double a$lzycompute() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if ((byte)(this.bitmap$0 & 0x1) == 0) {
                this.a = package..MODULE$.pow(5.0D, 1.0D); 
                this.bitmap$0 = ((byte)(this.bitmap$0 | 0x1)); 
            } 
            return this.a;
        }  
    } 

    private double b$lzycompute() { 
        synchronized (this) {
            if ((byte)(this.bitmap$0 & 0x2) == 0) {
                this.b = package..MODULE$.pow(5.0D, 2.0D); 
                this.bitmap$0 = ((byte)(this.bitmap$0 | 0x2)); 
            } 
            return this.b; 
        }  
    } 

    private double c$lzycompute() { 
        synchronized (this) {
            if ((byte)(this.bitmap$0 & 0x4) == 0) {
                this.c = package..MODULE$.pow(5.0D, 3.0D); 
                this.bitmap$0 = ((byte)(this.bitmap$0 | 0x4)); 
            } 
            return this.c;
        }
    }

    public double a() {
        return (byte)(this.bitmap$0 & 0x1) == 0 ? a$lzycompute() : this.a;
    }

    public double b() { 
        return (byte)(this.bitmap$0 & 0x2) == 0 ? b$lzycompute() : this.b; 
    } 

    public double c() { 
        return (byte)(this.bitmap$0 & 0x4) == 0 ? c$lzycompute() : this.c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, so it's using the fixed [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) available in Java 5.

Comment: If there are more `lazy` variables, is there a separate boolean flag for each of them? Or does Scala use some bit flags in such a case?

Comment: Updated the answer with another example containing three lazy variables. If you want to know what happens when it exceeds a byte, you can try it yourself ;)

Comment: Oh, and thanks for identifying this as double-checked locking. I learned something today.

Comment: @bwawok The first check is in `a()` before the lock. The second check is in `a$lzycompute()` after the lock.

Comment: @bwawok As far as I can tell the code we can see above only synchronizes when the value hasn't been computed yet. The flag is volatile so no need for a synchronised block.

Answer (score 0):

Update Scala 2.12.1 (Dec. 2016, three years later).

After [PR 5294 (Fields phase fully expands lazy vals and modules)](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5294), you can read in [commit 743f0d2](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/743f0d2c2a33bc8ab0c1f7bee796865672ba2fcc):

> ### Lazy val without local.
>
> Now `synchronized` is erased specially to avoid boxing, we can drop that work around.
>
> Note that this does add an extra cast and getter call on the slow path, but that likely doesn't matter.

```
class C { def foo = {lazy val x = {println("a"); "A" }; x } }
```

> becomes:

```
def foo(): String = {
  lazy <artifact> val x$lzy: scala.runtime.LazyRef[String] = new scala.runtime.LazyRef[String]();

  <artifact> private def x$lzycompute(): String =
    x$lzy.synchronized[String]{
      if (x$lzy.initialized())
        x$lzy.value() // NOTE: gets an `.asInstanceOf[String]` after erasure
      else
        {
          x$lzy.value_=({
            scala.Predef.println("a");
            "A"
          });
          x$lzy.initialized_=(true);
          x$lzy.value() // NOTE: gets an `.asInstanceOf[String]` after erasure
        }
    }

  lazy def x(): String =
    if (x$lzy.initialized())
      x$lzy.value() // NOTE: gets an `.asInstanceOf[String]` after erasure
    else
      x$lzycompute();

  x()
}
```