# Java bit operations

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to create a Java class that will hold some settings flags.
Class members:

- HEADER
- FOOTER
- LEFT_SECTION
- RIGHT_SECTION

These can be enabled/disabled.
I want to do it with bit wise operations but I was wondering if it's possible because I will not set all of them at a given time. I just want to set one and leave the others the same.

Give a current state `0100`, so only the `FOOTER` is enabled, is it possible to enable the `HEADER` and preserve the `FOOTER` flag value?

If my scenario is possible?

#### Main Class

```
package foo;

public class Main {

  private static final SectionVisible sectionVisible = new SectionVisible(); 

  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    // Enable FOOTER only
    sectionVisible.setValue(2); // 00000010
    printState();
    // Enable LEFT_SECTION but preserve FOOTER's value
    sectionVisible.setValue(4); // 00000100
    printState();
  }

  private static void printState() {
    System.out.println("header=" + sectionVisible.header());
    System.out.println("footer=" + sectionVisible.footer());
    System.out.println("leftSection=" + sectionVisible.leftSection());
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
  }

}
```

#### SectionVisible Class

```
package foo;

class SectionVisible {

  private static final Integer LEFT_SECTION_MASK = 4;
  private static final Integer LEFT_SECTION_OFFSET = 2;

  private static final Integer FOOTER_MASK = 2;
  private static final Integer FOOTER_OFFSET = 1;

  private static final Integer HEADER_MASK = 1;
  private static final Integer HEADER_OFFSET = 0;

  private Integer value;

  public Integer header() {
    return (value & HEADER_MASK) >> HEADER_OFFSET;
  }

  public Integer footer() {
    return (value & FOOTER_MASK) >> FOOTER_OFFSET;
  }

  public Integer leftSection() {
    return (value & LEFT_SECTION_MASK) >> LEFT_SECTION_OFFSET;
  }

  public void setValue(Integer value) {
    System.out.println(
        "Setting value to " + value + ":" + Integer.toBinaryString(value));
    this.value = value;
  }

}
```

#### Execution Log

```
Setting value to 2:10
header=0
footer=1
leftSection=0
----------------------------------------------------
Setting value to 4:100
header=0
footer=0
leftSection=1
----------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that when I'm setting the `LEFT_SECTION`'s value, I'm losing the `FOOTER`'s value.

Comment: Sure it is. But without code it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @LutzHorn Working on it.

Comment: As one example: [The implementation of lazy vals in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17642466/402884) involves packing boolean values into a `byte` as you describe.

Comment: I think you should start reading this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096916/real-world-use-cases-of-bitwise-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     static final int HEADER = 1;
     static final int FOOTER = 2;
     static final int LEFT_SECTION = 4;
     static final int RIGHT_SECTION = 8;

     int flags = 0;

     boolean isEnabledFooter() {
         return (flags & FOOTER) != 0;
     }

     void enableFooter() {
         flags |= FOOTER;
     }

     void disableFooter() {
         flags &= ~FOOTER;
     }
```

Comment: It works alright, but it's possible to change only the `flags` variable and set/unset the bits based on its binary value? I saw an example somewhere using a mask, but I forgot where.

Answer (score 1):

Use bitwise operators &, | and ^:

```
flags |= HEADER; // enable HEADER
if ((flags&FOOTER) != 0)
    ... do something when FOOTER is enabled...
```

Answer (score 0):

Each state has to be represented by an unique bit mask, usually called a **flag** (may be a single bit, or more than one bit, depending on the number of states).

```
public final static int HEADER = 0b0001;
public final static int FOOTER = 0b0010;
public final static int LEFT_SECTION = 0b0100;
public final static int RIGHT_SECTION = 0b1000;
```

You also need the packed state:

```
private int states=0;
```

Flags can be get and set as follows (bit arithmetic):

```
public boolean get (int flag) {
    return (states & flag) != 0;
}

public void set (int flag, boolean value) {
    states = value ? (states | flag) : (states & ~flag);
}
```

Usage:

```
// set header 
set(HEADER, true);
// unset header 
set(HEADER, false);
// read header 
boolean value = get(HEADER);
```