# Can a scala object constructor be run twice as race condition?

Tags: scala, thread-safety, companion-object

I have an object with vars that will change only from inside the object and during the initialisation / construction  of the object instance.

Can the same object constructor be run twice by accident in a race condition scenario? Or Scala offers proper checks to ensure it can only be run once?

Comment: A Scala `object` is a static singleton instance. How could the constructor by run twice?

Comment: When two threads access the same, non-initialised object, forcing it to be initialised at that time, (hopefully not) two times.

Comment: Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471402/what-is-the-proper-way-to-initialize-singleton-element-in-a-thread-safe-way-in-s and another thread I read sounds like you have to manage the locking/synchronization yourself.

Comment: @ameer That question wasn't about `object`s.

Comment: Usually this concern arises when you are using singletons (that, as mentioned, don't require any pattern in Scala and can be implemented with the `object` keyword – which uses locking to protect against this scenario). Can you post a snippet of code that could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe: the constructor runs in a static initializer. See e.g. http://blogs.tedneward.com/patterns/singleton-scala/.