# Is it correct behaviour that `lazy val` acts like `def` in case of exception?

Tags: scala, runtimeexception

I've noticed that `lazy val` repeats computation several times (in case of exception):

```
scala> lazy val aaa = {println("calc"); sys.error("aaaa")}
aaa: Nothing = <lazy>

scala> aaa
calc
java.lang.RuntimeException: aaaa
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at .aaa$lzycompute(<console>:7)
  at .aaa(<console>:7)
  ... 33 elided

scala> aaa
calc
java.lang.RuntimeException: aaaa
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at .aaa$lzycompute(<console>:7)
  at .aaa(<console>:7)
  ... 33 elided
```

Shouldn't it be like:

```
scala> aaa
calc
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not Initialized! 
caused by
java.lang.RuntimeException: aaaa

scala> aaa
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not Initialized! 
caused by
java.lang.RuntimeException: aaaa
```

Comment: That's how I read it should work, some time ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041253/whats-the-hidden-cost-of-scalas-lazy-val) post they explain very well how `lazy val` is compiled by the Scala compiler. Basically, if the evaluation of the expression fails, then the indicator-bit signaling that the `lazy val` contains its data won't be set.

**update1:**

I think one reason going with the first approach could be that the second one may be emulated by using two `lazy val`s, without burdening the underlying implementation with multiple volatile variables:

```
scala> lazy val _aaa = Try {println("calc"); sys.error("aaaa")}
_aaa: scala.util.Try[Nothing] = <lazy>

scala> lazy val aaa = _aaa.get
aaa: Nothing = <lazy>

scala> aaa
calc
java.lang.RuntimeException: aaaa
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at $anonfun$_aaa$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at $anonfun$_aaa$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
  at ._aaa$lzycompute(<console>:10)
  at ._aaa(<console>:10)
  at .aaa$lzycompute(<console>:11)
  at .aaa(<console>:11)
  ... 33 elided

scala> aaa
java.lang.RuntimeException: aaaa
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at $anonfun$_aaa$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at $anonfun$_aaa$1.apply(<console>:10)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
  at ._aaa$lzycompute(<console>:10)
  at ._aaa(<console>:10)
  at .aaa$lzycompute(<console>:11)
  at .aaa(<console>:11)
  ... 33 elided
```

**update2:**

As [@Silly Freak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371191/silly-freak) has proposed in his comment,

```
scala> lazy val _aaa = Try {println("calc"); sys.error("aaaa")}
_aaa: scala.util.Try[Nothing] = <lazy>

scala> def aaa = _aaa.get
aaa: Nothing
```

may work even better, as we can avoid having two `lazy val`s.

Comment: Already know about how it works.  My question is about correctness of approach or maybe better approach? As I believe, nothing stops them (as I see it) from implementing of correct exception handling inside lazy-compute.

Comment: I mean, they could have another bit for isFailure (at least) or remember the exception (at most, but more expensive). For now, `0` means both failure/not-initialized, so you can't distinguish them.

Comment: I can't really tell that, but probably for performance reasons (https://twitter.com/djspiewak/status/302489756552536064). For me both approach seems reasonable. Although it's not exactly the same, but depending on your use case, you may emulate your approach by doing `lazy val aaa = Try { println("calc"); sys.error("aaaa") }`

Comment: or even better: `lazy val _aaa = Try { println("calc"); sys.error("aaaa") }; lazy val aaa = _aaa.get`

Comment: I wouldn't agree about performance, but I like the workaround

Comment: @SillyFreak it can be, but if  _aaa contains a value, you may want to avoid calling `_aaa.get` each time

Comment: @kosii `_aaa` is either a `Success` or a `Failure`. If it's a success, then `get` has no side effects and it's ok to call it multiple times. If it's a failure, then `get` throws an exception, so the `lazy` won't cache it anyways. As I see it, making `aaa` a `lazy val` does not add anything semantically, no? And `lazy val` is more expensive than `def`.