# How to get truly atomic update for TrieMap.getOrElseUpdate

Tags: scala, concurrency, compare-and-swap

As I understand, `TrieMap.getOrElseUpdate` is still not truly atomic, and  [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7943) fixes only returned result (it could return different instances for different callers before this fix), so the updater function still might be called several times, as documentation (for 2.11.7) says:

> Note: This method will invoke op at most once. However, op may be invoked without the result being added to the map if a concurrent process is also trying to add a value corresponding to the same key k.

*I've checked that manually for 2.11.7, still "at least once"

How to guarantee one-time call (if I use TrieMap for factories)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution should work for my requirements:

```
trait LazyComp { val get: Int }

val map = new TrieMap[String, LazyComp]()

val count = new AtomicInteger() //just for test, you don't need it

def getSingleton(key: String) = {
  val v = new LazyComp {
    lazy val get = {
      //compute something
      count.incrementAndGet() //just for test, you don't need it
    }
  }
  map.putIfAbsent(key, v).getOrElse(v).get
}
```

I believe, `lazy val` actually uses synchronized inside. And also the code inside get should be [safe from exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742939/is-it-correct-behaviour-that-lazy-val-acts-like-def-in-case-of-exception)

However, performance could be improved in future: [SIP-20](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html)

Test:

```
scala> (0 to 10000000).par.map(_ => getSingleton("zzz")).last
res8: Int = 1
```

P.S. Java has `computeIfAbscent` method on `ConcurrentHashMap` which I could use as well.

Comment: Why not even ``lazy val v = ...``?

Comment: it will not work. If you run my test - you'll get more than one (I've got 3)

Comment: @JeanLogeart that's because second parameter of putIfAbsent is not lazy

Comment: @JeanLogeart same problem for getOrElseUpdate. Regardless that it has call-by-name parameter for updater - it sill calls it at inappropriate time.