# Does it make sense to use "private[this] lazy val"?

Tags: scala

I understand why it is useful to do 
`private[this] val xx = 3` 
as explained on https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#privatethis.

Does the same apply to `lazy val` as well?
Q1. Is 
`private[this] lazy val xx = 3` 
faster than
`private val xx = 3` ?

Q2. `def f(i: Int) = i`
Is `private[this] lazy val xx = f(3)` 
faster than
`private val xx = f(3)` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? It's just different.

Comment: Do you really think that declaring `val` as public would really degrade the performance of your application?

Comment: @4lex1v: Nope, Just curious. Bdw both are private.

Comment: I find the original suggestion of using private[this] instead of private a bit strange, as the two are not semantically equivalent: a private val is accessible by other instances of the same class, while a private[this] val is accessible only in that instance.

Comment: @csgero: See the example here: https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#privatethis, I'm looking for the answer on the lines of the example there.

Comment: `lazy val` definitely **could not** be degraded to just field without an accessor as long as it should implement logic to determine whether value was already calculated or not.

Comment: @Odomontois: That was  what was on my head, But I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
The generated class for a class with `private lazy val x= 3` and `private[this] lazy val =3` are identical and the explanation is as follows.

**`private lazy val`**

```
public class LazyValTest
{
  private int bar;
  private volatile boolean bitmap$0;

  private int bar$lzycompute()
  {
    synchronized (this) { if (!this.bitmap$0) { this.bar = 3; this.bitmap$0 = true; } return this.bar; }  } 
  private int bar() { return this.bitmap$0 ? this.bar : bar$lzycompute();
  }
}
```

There is a slight difference in class generated using private and private[this] val.

**`private val`**

```
public class PrivateValTest
{
  private final int bar = 3;

  private int bar() { return this.bar; }
}
```

**`private[this] val`**

```
public class PrivateThisValTest
{
  private final int bar = 3;
}
```

Comment: linked article dictates precisely *For performance sensitive code, prefer `private[this]` over `private`* . So I think it's says "it's faster"

Answer (score 2):

No - a lazy val is always encoded as a method with a backing field, so `private[this]` or not you will always [pay the cost of the accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3041253/135978) if you make the value lazy. The JIT compiler *may* later recognize that it can inline the backing field access (after the first load) but the style guide you reference seems to be focused on performance guarantees and that sort of inlining does not seem guaranteed right now.