# How good is Scala By-name parameters performance?

Tags: performance, scala, lazy-evaluation, callbyname

I know how scala by-name parameters work: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html

I'm using it in a very sensitive piece of code that gets run a lot.
My questions is: Is there any performance or memory drawback?
For example, I know using lazy val has its drawbacks: [What's the (hidden) cost of Scala's lazy val?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041253/whats-the-hidden-cost-of-scalas-lazy-val)

Is there something similar about by-name parameters? How are they implemented underneath?

Please note I will NOT be using it with lazy for caching. So I wouldn't have that above mentioned problem. I just need to know under the hood it's not using lazy itself.

Thanks

Comment: well... they are similar to functions... and are often combined with lazy...

Comment: Updated to post to clarify, I will not use lazy val for caching it. I will use a var. So wouldn't have the lazy problem. Just need to know how it's implemented under the hood and if there is any issue with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By name parameters are implemented as instances of `Function1`. So they also have the same performance characteristics.

Calling a method with a by name parameter has the overhead of creating an instance of `Function1` and using the by name parameter has the overhead of calling the method `apply` on a `Function1` object.